# Echo used hierarchical taxonomies parent name

Tags: taxonomy, terms

I want to echo my hierarchical taxonomies parents which I used in my posts.
I've see answers about that, but no one didn't help me.

To get all taxonomies, currently I use

```
<?php the_terms( $post->ID, 'mytaxname', '', ' / ', ' ' ); ?>`
```

How to get only parents of used tax's?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
<?php
  $term = get_term_by( 'slug', get_query_var( 'term' ), get_query_var( 'taxonomy' ) );
  $parent = get_term($term->parent, get_query_var('taxonomy') );

  echo $parent->name;
?>
```

You have to get the current term slug and then use [get_term](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_term) by the slug and then echo the name.

Comment: Thank you for answer. But this code doesn't echo anything. I changed `'taxonomy'` to my taxonomy name, nothing happens :(

Comment: I dont think you need to change taxonomy to something else.

Comment: Look, my hierarchical taxonomy name (slug) is called "Role".
How WordPress must recognize, which taxonomy i want to echo?)

Comment: Maybe i must use `$post->ID` somewhere?

Comment: this code doesn't echo anything :(

Comment: `get_query_var( 'term' )` and `get_query_var( 'taxonomy' )` aren't set on a single post page, only on tax or term pages.

Comment: but i need for single pages!

Comment: Ziya, WordPress needs to know the taxonomys name, but Pontus is automagically grabbing via get_query_var. If you want to manually specify if replace "get_query_var('taxonomy')" with your taxonomies name

Comment: Also -100000 for calling your taxonomy "Role" that's a reserved name, change it to something else as you'll have lots of horrible, painful problems

Answer (score 0):

I'm not the BEST with PHP, but... This returns a list of taxonomy terms attached to a post via the taxonomy name. It will only display the parent terms of the taxonomy names.

```
    <?
$args = array( 'taxonomy' => 'YOUR_TERM_NAME', 'parent' => 0 );
$terms = get_terms('YOUR_TERM_NAME', $args);
$count = count($terms); $i=0;
if ($count > 0) {
    foreach ($terms as $term) {
        $i++;
        $term_list .= '<a href="?YOUR_TERM_NAME=' . $term->slug . '" title="' . sprintf(__('View all post filed under %s'), $term->name) . '">' . $term->name . '</a>';
        if ($count != $i) $term_list .= ' &middot; '; else $term_list .= '';
    }
    echo $term_list;
}
?>
```

It will also link to the archive page for each term. You can repeat this within your post's loop as many times as you like for each taxonomy you want to display. That's the part that I feel isn't very clean, I'm sure there's a way to display multiple taxonomies in one function, but I can't do that. The above achieves what you want, though.